# No plot for DC current gain in datasheet

Tags: transistors, current, dc, npn, gain

Here is the data-sheet:
https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N4401.pdf

I want to use a 2N4401 NPN transistor in active region for amplification, and I want to know its beta(DC current gain) value in this region. (I thought it was a fixed value).

In saturation mode there is only one beta value and it is 10. There is even a plot for that: Vcesat vs Ic plot in page 4.

But if my aim is to use this transistor for amplification, and when I look at the data sheet there are many beta values(DC current gains): two Vce values 1.0V and 2.0V.

In general, if Vce is greater than 0.2V the transistor is in amplification region isn't it? I though the beta is a constant in that region.

Mt questions are:

1-)What if Vce is a different number lets say 5V. What would be the DC gain? There's no plot about it.

2-)Is my assumption wrong about transistors which is: DC current gain(beta) is almost constant in amplification mode?

Comment: A bit further down there is Small Signal Current Gain hfe = 40-500. Those are the values you need for an amplifier. It pays to read the whole data sheet carefully.

Comment: Oh so the gain changes that much. I thought Ic and Ib has linear relation in that region

Comment: What is DC current gain?? There is gain at saturation mode and it is 10. There is the one u mentioned. Buth what left? What is Dc current gain in this data sheet??

Comment: DC current gain, hFE,  is stated.

Comment: There is two hfe in the data sheet. One is stated as small signal current gain and the other is stated as DC current gain. Both are named as hfe. If the first one is beta in amplification mode what is the second one about?

Comment: if I use a pwm signal which one is relevant?

Comment: One is hfe, the other is hFE!

Comment: "if I use a pwm signal which one is relevant?" It depends on your circuit and what you're doing with the PWM signal. Are you switching the NPN on/off with the PWM signal or are you amplifying it linearly ? Show us your circuit so we can figure out which parameters matter.

Comment: I messed up I ll make a new question with screen shots

Comment: @FakeMoustache here I made a new question I hope more clear: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206391/a-confusion-on-the-current-gain-of-an-npn-transistor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: -

[image]

And then there is this: -

[image]

That's a fair bit of information to find in a BJT data sheet. But, if in doubt, use a sim and get the Fairchild model of the part.

Comment: Isnt hfe constant in amplification region?

Comment: Who said it would be? See "Early effect": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect

Comment: By the way what is DC current gain?? There is gain at saturation mode and it is 10. There is the one other user has mentioned small sig gain. But what left? What is Dc current gain in this data sheet??

Comment: hFE is the dc current gain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#h-parameter_model

Comment: There is two hfe in the data sheet. One is stated as small signal current gain and the other is stated as DC current gain. Both are named as hfe. If the first one is beta in amplification mode what is the second one about?

Comment: if I use a pwm signal which one is relevant?

Comment: Assuming that PWM will cause the BJT to saturate, the hFE of 10 is the valid or most applicable number. BTW I'd probably use a mosfet reading between the lines. Regards the hFe you refer to I cannot tell you which one is which because I don't know which one you are looking at. I'd use the graphs for typical values.

Comment: One hfe is called DC current gain. There is another hfe called small signal gain. They both have same names.

Comment: Small signal current gain is for non-saturating linear applications (Vce = 10V). The DC current gain (higher up in the table) is more like for power applications like PWM because the collector emitter voltage is closer to zero volts i.e. Vce = 1V or 2V. This information should be reflected in the graphs and this is the end of the tutorial!!

Comment: One is hfe, the other is hFE! Note the difference.

Answer (score 1):

What it comes down to is this:

You cannot reliably predict the gain of an amplifier from an hfe number in a datasheet. Or hFE - loosely, small signal and DC current gains.

Therefore, if you need an accurately defined gain, you must define the gain yourself.

For example, by using an amplifier with relatively high gain (say, at least 10x the gain required) and reducing the gain to the required value with a [negative feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_feedback) network. This is a well known way of reducing the dependence of amplifier gain on transistor gain.

Andy has given you some of the reasons : hfe varies with Vce, Ic, probably temperature, it may drift as the transistor ages (especially if the transistor is thermally stressed ) and may vary between 50 and 400 between different batches of the same model transistor.

You may be asking the wrong question. If so, your best option would be to indicate the gain you want, the accuracy you need (e.g. gain = 40 +/- 5%, or gain between 38 and 42) and ask for hints how to do that with specific transistors.

---

However one of the comments clarifies that you are asking about PWM. If you are talking about the actual PWM output transistors, you should be operating them either fully saturated or fully off, and nowhere in between. In which case, the ONLY hFE rating you need is the saturation one.

Saturation is not a sudden event but reflects the rapid decrease in hFE as Vce reduces : for reasons of convenience, the usual definition of saturation is the point where hFE = 10.

Therefore, take hFE=10 and calculate the base current you need from that.

Comment: Actually I totally messed up. My real problem when I plot Ic/Ib of a transistor at a constant Vce with varying Ib, I get a very weird beta at amplification region. But tutorials say beta is constant

Comment: I do it in Ltspice

Comment: My question is about amplification zone

Comment: I can upload a screenshot if u want

Comment: Dummond  here I made a new question I hope more clear: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206391/a-confusion-on-the-current-gain-of-an-npn-transistor